# Wordpress dashboard widget - Using wp_enqueue_style/wp_enqueue_script breaks the dashboard

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a wordpress dashboard widget, and i want to use bootstrap to make a UI.

This is my code:

```
    <?php


    add_action("wp_dashboard_setup","hlele_add_dashboard_widget");




    function hlele_enqueue_bootstrap(){
        // JS
        wp_enqueue_script('hlele_bootstrap_js' , 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' );

        // CSS
        wp_enqueue_style('hlele_bootstrap_css' , 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

    }



    function hlele_add_dashboard_widget(){
        hlele_enqueue_bootstrap();
        wp_add_dashboard_widget("hlele_sysinfo_dashboard","System Information","hlele_setSysInfo");
    }

    function hlele_setSysInfo(){
       echo '<a class="btn btn-danger">Test</a>';
    }





?>
```

When i run this, the dashboard seems to 'break'(not sure what's going on...)

The font of the dashboard text changes from the default font to bootstrap's default font and the Screen Options and Help buttons seem to have stopped working.

Answer (score -1):

When you create new widget you can not use

```
add_action
```

You must add

```
wp_enqueue_style
```

in

```
public function __construct
```

For example

```
public function __construct() {
        $widget_id = 'contact_form';
        $widget_name = __('Formularz Kontaktowy', 'ContactForm');
        $widget_opt = array('description'=>'Ten widget wyświetla formularz kontaktowy.');

        parent::__construct($widget_id, $widget_name, $widget_opt);

      wp_enqueue_style( 'contact-form-style', get_theme_file_uri( '/widgets/css/contactform.css' ) );
     }
```

EDIT:
I tested code in my WordPress, and your code works -
[Show me the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwLGQ.png)

Comment: Show me your widget file.

Comment: where is the widget file? Sorry I'm just a beginner at WordPress plugins

Comment: Probably you have problem in other place in functions.php. Show me your functions.php.